# Use of command "xssstate " in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, screensaver, autostart

I want **to access the screensaver state of ubuntu** (when my laptop is idle for some minute) . And *run an application if screensaver start and if I click or stir mouse pad then application should exit as screensaver exit*.

After searching on google I come to a command

```
  xssstate -i
```

But I don't know what it does and How can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xssstate -s` to check out screensaver's status:

```
$ xssstate -s
off
```

then based on the output decide what you have to do.

`-i` returns X's idle time.

You can create a simple script and run it using `cron` then on that script use `xssstate` to see if you have to run or end your program.

Comment: Is there any other command that I can use to capture the status of screensaver. I don't want to install any extra package.

Comment: What's wrong with `xssstate`? it's from "suckless-tools" and really lightweight. You can also use `xprintidle` but you have to install that too.